# how to remove or disable ionic 5 default splash screen ionic version 5

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor, ionic5

How can I replace Ionic 5 default splash screen with a custom HTML  or Lottie one?

[default spash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UMKO.png)

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "safenotes",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "firebase": "^8.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like only png files are supported at the moment.

You need to use [Capacitor Assets](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons) (formerly known as cordova-res).

Install it globally:

```
$ npm install -g cordova-res
```

Than prepare the following files in the `resources` folder:

```
resources/
├── android
|   ├── icon-background.png (1)
|   └── icon-foreground.png (1)
├── icon.png
└── splash.png
config.xml (2)
```

Then generate all the required icons and splash screens with:

```
$ cordova-res
```

You can also use the `--copy`option to automatically copy the files into the android/ios projects, e.g.:

```
$ cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy
$ cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

(1) These icons are only necessary if you want [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) for android to be generated. They must be present if your android project already uses default adaptive icons from capacitor.

(2) Config file is optional as well, check [the docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets) for updated instructions and many more details.